# Javascript function does not act as expected

Tags: javascript

I have two JS scripts but neither of them does what I want to see.
I tried Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer. All the same.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="demo1">123</p>
    <p id="demo2">456</p>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS - script 1

```
function arrEmpty(arr){
    arr.splice(0, arr.length);
    return arr;
}
const arrEle = [1,2,3,4,5];  
const result = arrEmpty(arrEle);
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = arrEle.toString();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result.toString();
```

Expected Result:

[1,2,3,4,5]

[]

Result - Empty arrays in both lines:

[]

[]

JS - script 2

```
function arrEmpty(arr){
    arr.length = 0;
    return arr;
}
const arrEle = [1,2,3,4,5];  
const result = arrEmpty(arrEle);
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = arrEle.toString();
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result.toString();
```

Expected Result:

[1,2,3,4,5]

[]

Result - Empty arrays in both lines:

[]

[]

Why is it that?

It works only if I swap the line before the function.

JS - script Modified:

```
function arrEmpty(arr){
    arr.length = 0;
    return arr;
}
const arrEle = [1,2,3,4,5];  
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = arrEle.toString();
const result = arrEmpty(arrEle);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result.toString();
```

Comment: Quick test on my end: both code samples work as expected for me. You sure you're actually testing the code shown here? (note with both functions you will alter the array also outside of the function - here, JS behaves like copy by reference).

Comment: The console has a live reference to the array, so when you expand the array after calling the function, it shows the empty array. Use `console.log(JSON.stringify(arrEle))`